# Finding implicit values in the companion object of a nested type

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

I have a trait `Outer` with a member `F` that is a type constructor. I want to supply type-class instances for `F`, but somehow at one point the implicit resolution of `scalac` stops working.

I tried to build a smaller minimal example, but I had to add everything below to make the error appear. Note how the second-to-last line still compiles, properly picking up the implicit from the nested companion object in `sub`.

But the last line doesn't compile anymore. Also note that when specifying the implicit method in the second-to-last line, it compiles.

Can anyone provide a clue for why this happens?

```
trait TC[F[_]]

trait Outer[N[_]] {
  trait F[_]
  object F {
    implicit val tcInst: TC[F] = new TC[F]{}
  }
}

case class Sub[N[_]]() extends Outer[N]

object Test{
  implicit val optionInst: TC[Option] = new TC[Option]{}

  val sub = Sub[Option]()
  val sub2 = Sub[sub.F]()

  implicitly[TC[sub.F]]                  //compiles
  implicitly[TC[sub2.F]](sub2.F.tcInst)  //compiles
  implicitly[TC[sub2.F]]                 //doesn't compile
}
```

The last line yields the following error:

```
Error:(22, 13) could not find implicit value for parameter e: test.novariance.TC[test.novariance.Test.sub2.F]
  implicitly[TC[sub2.F]]                 //doesn't compile
            ^
Error:(22, 13) not enough arguments for method implicitly: (implicit e: test.novariance.TC[test.novariance.Test.sub2.F])test.novariance.TC[test.novariance.Test.sub2.F].
Unspecified value parameter e.
  implicitly[TC[sub2.F]]                 //doesn't compile
            ^
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I can see why your implicit doesn't resolve, so I'll try to explain why it doesn't satisfy the scoping rules.</strike>

But I'm not clear what your intent is, so I can't suggest a workaround.

Step by step:

1. To satisfy this expression `implicitly[TC[sub2.F]]`, the compiler will search lexical (surrounding) scope, and then the companions (if any) of types `TC` and `sub2.F.type` (ie the type of the object `F` nested within `Outer`).
2. In lexical scope there is only `TC[Option]`, which isn't the same type as  `sub2.F.type`.
3. In companion scope, `TC` has no companion object. `sub2.F` isn't a class, its an object, so it cannot have a companion object.

If you meant to refer to the trait `F` within `Outer`, you need the *type projection* operator `#`, eg `sub2#F`

Comment: I don't understand your answer completely. Does it also explain why  `implicitly[TC[sub.F]]` compiles?

Comment: In truth, I see now that my answer is wrong. I was under the mistaken belief that in expression `TC[sub.F]`, `F` referred to the object `F`. 

But actually, scala's subtly overloaded syntax means that within a type context, `sub.F` refers to the type of trait F.